# FAME: How do I combine 2 data objects (each a list of series)?

Tags: database

I am not sure if anyone here is familiar with FAME as it is not commonly used.

But here is my code

```
DB="C:\..."
 
A_DATA="Profit.20?.FIRM_A"
B_DATA="Revenue.20?.FIRM_XX"

EXEC "OPEN <AC RE> """ + DB + """ AS OPENEDDATABASE" -- BASE STORING RAW DATA SERIES
NLIST = WILDLIST(OPENEDDATABASE,A_DATA)
NLIST2 = WILDLIST(OPENEDDATABASE,B_DATA)
```

I want to combine NLIST & NLIST2 into a single variable. But there doesn't seem any FAME function that allows me to do.

Put in another way, I need to have all the series named "Profit.20?.FIRM_A" and "Revenue.20?.FIRM_XX"
in 1 variable.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

unless I misunderstand something, namelists in FAME can simply be added together with the '+' operator:

```
fruits = {apples,oranges}
vegetables = {cabbage,carrots}

food = fruits + vegetables

type !food

apples,oranges,cabbage,carrots
```